# React Native Post call from a function using Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios, react-hooks

I'm new to React Native, so please excuse my incompetence. I'm trying to call a axios post from a function but getting an error. Can someone please look at my code and tell me where I'm going wrong or how to post using axios. What I'm trying to do is build a simple timeclock and post timestamp data along with type(clock_in or Clock_out) to my rest generated via spring boot)

```
    const TimeclockScreen = ({navigation}) => {

    const ClockFunc = () => {
        const [TimeClockFunc, setTimeClockFunc] = useState(
            { timeclock_type: '', tc_timestamp: { dt } //Dt is the realtime Clock Data}
        );
        const handleChange = (event) => {
            setTimeClockFunc({ ...TimeClockFunc, [event.target.name]: event.target.value })
        }

        const handleSubmit = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            axios.post('http://localhost:8080/timeclocks', TimeClockFunc)
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response)
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                })
        }
    }

    const [ClockInEnabled, setClockInEnabled] = useState(true);
    const [ClockOutEnabled, setClockOutEnabled] = useState(false);

    const [dt, setDt] = useState(new Date().toLocaleString());

    useEffect(() => {
        let secTimer = setInterval(() => {
            setDt(new Date().toLocaleString())
        }, 1000)

        return () => clearInterval(secTimer);
    }, []);

    const handleClockInPressed = () => {
        setClockInEnabled(false);
        setClockOutEnabled(true);
        this.handleSubmit();
        alert('Clocked In');
    };

    const handleClockOutPressed = () => {
        setClockInEnabled(true);
        setClockOutEnabled(false);
        this.handleSubmit();
        alert('Clocked Out')
    };
return(
<View style={styles.container}>

            <Text>{'\n'}{'\n'}{'\n'}{dt}</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    disabled={!ClockInEnabled}
                    onPress={handleClockInPressed}
                    style={[styles.button, {
                        borderColor: '#009387',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        marginTop: 15
                    }]}
                </TouchableOpacity>

             
                <TouchableOpacity
                    disabled={!ClockOutEnabled}
                    onPress={handleClockOutPressed}
                    style={[styles.button, {
                        borderColor: '#009387',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        marginTop: 15
                    }]}
                </TouchableOpacity>

          <View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is now resolved. I used the 192.168 Ip address of my local machine and it worked.